# How to use limit definition to find derivative with a radical

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

I'm trying to find the derivative of $f(x)=3\sqrt x$ at $25$. How would you go about this using the limit definition of a derivative? I'm currently stuck at $(3\sqrt{25+h}+15)/h$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(25+h)-f(25)}{h}&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{3\sqrt{25+h}-3\sqrt{25}}{h}\\\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\left(\frac{3\sqrt{25+h}-3\sqrt{25}}{h}\,\times\frac{\sqrt{25+h}+\sqrt{25}}{\sqrt{25+h}+\sqrt{25}}\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{3}{\sqrt{25+h}+\sqrt{25}}\\\\
&=\frac{3}{10}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you for showing/explaining. I would upvote if I could.

Comment: You're quite welcome.  My pleasure.  You can accept the answer is you choose.